# Elasticsearch cURL query string in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am using elasticsearch to get some kind of information about my users.

I just made a script in PHP that parses a document by using cURL and it is sending requests like:

`http://something.something/test*/_search?q=%2Blogin:"jack"%20%2Bdate:"*May%20%20%201"%20%2Broom:"nameOfRoom"&default_operator=AND&size=99999999`

Which, decoded, is:

`http://something.something/test*/_search?q=+login:"jack" +date:"*May   1" +room:"nameOfRoom"&default_operator=AND&size=99999999`

Instead of getting records about Jack from May 1st (yeah there is triple space) that was in the "nameOfRoom" room I am getting stuff from whole May with logins like "--jack" "*jack" etc.

Can someone provide info how to build more complicated query like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin-head for elasticsearch wich provide tools helping you building complex queries:

http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/